# Sitecore workflow approve related items

Tags: workflow, workbox

I am using a very simple workflow with get approval and waiting for approval and approved

My problem is, that we have some large releases of content and sometimes some content is not allowed to get released. So I need the possibility to only get the approval for some specific pages and that all related Items are also moving to waiting for approval for this page/s. Because to see which items are related to my content in the workbox is not possible.

So I was hoping there is a setting or something like this that I cann approve related Items.

Comment: "all related Items" - what do you mean by this, all datasource items related to the main page item being approved?

Comment: yes all Datasource items and linked items in the datasources from the page I want to approve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to publish related item of page so in "Auto Publish" action in parameters field, you can set "related=1" which will publish related items as mentioned in this link http://sitecorepromenade.blogspot.com/2015/10/workflow-with-auto-publish-related-items.html?m=1

In case if you want to publish item manually and you want to approve all related item, this link https://pageditor.wordpress.com/2014/11/14/approving-related-items-in-a-workflow/ could be your possibly solution

Comment: no I don't mean "Auto publish" I want to publish manually, but I want to be able to approve all related Items to a site I want to approve, because in the workbox there is no filter for page/site approval.

Comment: In this case, you need to do some custom code, can you please check this code https://pageditor.wordpress.com/2014/11/14/approving-related-items-in-a-workflow/ ?

Comment: Yes this was the right link to solve my problem, when you could change your answer to this url I can mark your answer as solution

Comment: Updated answer thanks